# Order of linked sections in PE files

Tags: windows, linker, portable-executable

According to the PE format specification:

"However, the characters following the “$” determine the ordering of the contributions to the image section. All contributions with the same object-section name are allocated contiguously in the image, and the blocks of contributions are sorted in lexical order by object-section name. Therefore, everything in object files with section name .text$X ends up together, after the .text$W contributions and before the .text$Y contributions."

What's the use case for this? I wouldn't expect code to care what order sections are linked in the executable. Are there any cases where it does?

Comment: Yes in CRT for example.

Comment: @Xearinox Okay, how/why does CRT need this? What would break if the order were changed?

Comment: This is important order. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918180.aspx

Comment: Yup.  In general a way to get the linker to build a table for you that contains data from different translation units.